# Does the power iteration method for finding eigenvalues work for non diagonalizable matrices? Why or why not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

I have the proof that it works for diagonalizable matrices But does it work for the other category also? If it does or does not, how do I prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Try power iteration with 
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 }, \ \pmatrix{0 & 1\\1& 0}, \ \pmatrix{0 & 1\\-1& 0}.
$$

Comment: Only the first matrix you wrote is non-diagonalizable. However the problem with all of them is that they have 2 eigenvalues of the same "size". It has nothing to do with the diagonalizability of the matrix.